# Argument of type 'By' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Predicate<DebugElement>'

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, protractor

I'm experimenting with Protractor (5.4.2) and trying to test my Angular component.
I created the following test, inspired by the [Unit testing in Angular course](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/unit-testing-angular/table-of-contents) from Joe Eames.

**The (working) example from the course**
[image]

**My (faulty) code**

```js
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { DetailsComponent } from './details.component';
import { By } from 'protractor';

describe('DetailsComponent', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<DetailsComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [DetailsComponent]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(DetailsComponent);

        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

     it('contains 3 titles', () => {
        expect(fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.card-title')).length).toBe(3);
    });
});
```

However, the following type error occurres in the *.query* invocation in the test method:

> Argument of type 'By' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Predicate'.

I don't understand why this error occurs as my code looks similair to the example.

Comment: import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

Comment: not sure what the difference is, but if you use an IDE with a helper it shows that the By needs to come from @angualr/platform-browser which is used for finding elements for testing

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This error occurred because you imported `By` from the `protractor` instead of the `@angular/platform-browser` module.

Change this `import { By } from 'protractor';`  to the `import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';`